# Pagination data wont sort by search condition when trying to change the page in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a problems on the pagination spesificly when try to searching data by some condition its work properly, But when i try to change the page the data wont sort by the condition.the the search work properly but it gone wrong when i change the page.

this is my code

```
    public function fotoTrxSearch(Request $request){

    $transaction = Foto::OrderByDesc('id');

    if($request->filled('name')){
        $transaction->where('name', 'like', "%{$request->name}%")->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    if($request->filled('from') AND $request->filled('to')){
        $transaction->whereBetween('date', [$request->get('from'), $request->get('to')])->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    if($request->filled('price')){
        $transaction->where('price','like', "%{$request->price}%")->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    if($request->filled('folder')){
        $transaction->where('folder','like', "%{$request->folder}%")->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    
    $transaction = new FotoCollection($transaction->paginate(150));

    return Inertia::render('Foto/FotoList',[ 'fotos' => $transaction]);
   
}
```

please give me some clue or hint, solution to fix this problems
Thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, your conditions work properly only on the first page. On any other they don't work. If that's the case, I think this code should solve your problem, because it worked for me:

```
       $result = $transactions->paginate(150)
        ->appends(request()->query());
       ...
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

You should persist the query result to a variable before pagination. This might work:

```
public function fotoTrxSearch(Request $request){

    $transactions = Foto::OrderByDesc('id');

    if($request->filled('name')){
        $transactions = Foto::where('name', 'like', "%{$request->name}%")->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    if($request->filled('from') AND $request->filled('to')){
        $transactions = Foto::whereBetween('date', [$request->get('from'), $request->get('to')])->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    if($request->filled('price')){
        $transactions = Foto::where('price','like', "%{$request->price}%")->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    if($request->filled('folder')){
        $transactions = Foto::where('folder','like', "%{$request->folder}%")->orderBy( 'id', 'desc');
    }
    
    $transactions = new FotoCollection($transactions->paginate(150));

    return Inertia::render('Foto/FotoList',[ 'fotos' => $transactions]);
   
}
```

Comment: you need to declare $result first if you want to use it , and you cant paginate $result which is empty